# IIS - Custom Application Pool identity not being used

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

I have an ASP.NET web application that uses an Application Pool with a custom identity set to connect to DB via Trusted Authentication.

I have this working correctly on a dozen servers, yet I am having an issue with one: IIS is not using the custom identity and is instead attempting to impersonate the user when initiating the DB connection.

I verified I have the app pool configured to use the custom account and my web.config has `<identity impersonate="false"/>`. In fact I'm using an exact copy of the code and web.config from another properly working box.

I do have Windows Authentication enabled for the app to get the user login, but not for impersonation, and this is working correctly on 12 of 13 servers. If I disable Windows Authentication on the impacted box, I get `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` when accessing the site.

I tried recreating the application pool and the the IIS Application to no avail.

Anyone seen this behavior before? I'm running out of ideas. Thanks!

- ASP.NET MVC4
- IIS 7.5
- Server 2008 R2 64bit

Comment: from iis can you see the app pool application is using ? Make sure your application is using actual app pool you configured.

Comment: Yep--the app is using the correct application pool